# Entity Framework Can't modify data in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagrid

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework but i have little problem i can not solve by myself
I'm loading data from MS SQL database to the datagrid and trying to modify/add data from there.
But i don't know how to achieve this.
Here is my code:

```
    using (var context = new OrdersDataModelContainer())
        {
            var customersQuery = from o in context.Payments
                                 select o;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customersQuery;
        }
```

when i did it this way i get this:

[image: ScreenShot 1]

when i modyfy code:

```
    using (var context = new OrdersDataModelContainer())
        {
            var customersQuery = from o in context.Payments
                                 select o;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customersQuery.ToList();
        }
```

my form looks :

[image]

But then i can not modify data or add new rows.

Can anyone help me with this problem by showing some code snippet or pointing where I'll be able to find solution?

Thanks!

@Update
I use VS 2012 and SQL Server 2012 ( if that matters)

Comment: Why not? you don't even use any `Saving code` so how could you update?

Comment: Ok but I can't even change anything in datagrid cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the underlying data source of the grid does not support modification. Solution:

```
using (var context = new OrdersDataModelContainer())
{
    var customersQuery = from o in context.Payments
                         select o;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Payments>(customersQuery.ToList());
}
```

*Thanks to King King's comment*

**Update:**
To save changes you need to preserve the context which actually tracks the modifications on the retrieved entities that are now presented in the grid. So one way (perhaps the simplest way) is to declare context as a form member:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     private MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext(); // whatever your context name is

     private void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // when you want to load the data
     {
        var customersQuery = from o in context.Payments
                             select o;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Payments>(customersQuery.ToList());
     }

     private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // when you want to save
     {  
       context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Be advised that `context` is not recommended to be preserved for a long time. There are many articles about life cycle of the context.

Comment: it should be `new BindingList<Payments>(customersQuery.ToList())`

Comment: Thanks! Can You tell me one more thing where I should add saveChanges() to remember changes?

Comment: @szpic To save changes you need to preserve the *context*. I update the answer in a minute to show you how.

Comment: @Alireza thanks! with this code snippet I can modify data but can't add new rows. On Id is identity(1,1) and any row added is omitted and not saved in database.

Comment: @szpic This is because the context is not notified about the added rows. You can search the web for finding a solution since there are many ways to accomplish this. One way is to search the grid to find rows with Id=0. Another way is to handle *UserAddedRow* event and keep the index of the added row. Better way is to use a BindingSource. There are some tutorials out there.